# SSIS and WCF webservice

Tags: wcf, ssis

I need to populate a table B by selecting a from table A but for every single record selected from Table A for some of the fields I need to pass it to a WCF webservice and do some tasks.

Can somebody show me an example on how to invoke a WCF webservice for every single row fetched from a database through a script component

A step by step example would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS allows you to call a web service, you can use this to call a WCF service with basic http binding

The blog post in the folling link contains a link to a video on how to do ths.

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/06/19/SSIS_3A00_--Consuming-web-services-in-SSIS-2008.aspx